# dockerfile java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5B["

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a project using docker. This is my docker file. It throws the error from the title.

```
FROM java:8

ADD krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
ADD report.jar report.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch report.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://audpro_mongo/report","-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/report.jar"]
```

If I remove

```
"-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf"
```

project builds succesfully. I guess it's because of `mongodb:` and `file:` from other properties, but I've started using docker a couple days ago and have no idea why they are there and what I should use for the property I added.

Any advice?

Comment: have you tried  krb5.conf file elsewhere? Are you sure it contains no errors?

Comment: @white I used it for authorization in CLI. There were no errors.

Comment: Run a java container and test inside it manually. You may not have some required dependencies which may be needed for `/etc/krb5.conf` config to work

Comment: Are you able to run your spring application successfully without using Docker will all the -D agruments ?

Comment: @yamenk Yes. There are no problems running it without docker.

Comment: @yamenk Correction. I don't pass it anything when running without docker. Mongo is deployed locally and the krb5 is unnecessary, because I have a ticket which is used automaticaly.